# Semantics of the RRX shift instruction in ARM and Carry flag updates?

Tags: assembly, arm

Still looking at ARM assembler semantics (and, I try hard to read the specification, I ensure you!!!). I have some doubts about the ARM bit-shift instructions in general and `RRX` in particular.

Lets start with `RRX`.

From [Davespace, Introduction to ARM, section *Barrel Shifter*](http://www.davespace.co.uk/arm/introduction-to-arm/barrel-shifter.html), we see that `RRX` correspond to:

[image: RRX: Barrel RollRotate Right Extended]

I suppose the `C` to be the carry flag found in the CPSR, is it correct ?

Second question, in the case of the following instruction:

```
ands   r9, r0, r0, ror #3
```

I read that the carry flag (`C`) is set to the value of the last bit shifted out by the shifter operand (here `ROR`).

My problem is that the `ands` is also supposed to update the CPSR because of its flag `s`. So, who is winning at the end ? And, what is left in the final carry flag ? The value resulting of `AND` or the value resulting of `ROR` ?

Comment: I know that I should try, but I have no easy ARM platform with a debugger at hand reach by now... (though an ARM QEmu could do it as well...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, `C` is the carry flag.
2. `C` is set from the result of the `ROR` operation.

Pseudocode of the `AND (register)` instruction from the [ARM ARM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0406c/index.html):

```
if ConditionPassed() then
    EncodingSpecificOperations();
    (shifted, carry) = Shift_C(R[m], shift_t, shift_n, APSR.C);
    result = R[n] AND shifted;
    if d == 15 then // Can only occur for ARM encoding
        ALUWritePC(result); // setflags is always FALSE here
    else
        R[d] = result;
        if setflags then
            APSR.N = result<31>;
            APSR.Z = IsZeroBit(result);
            APSR.C = carry;
            // APSR.V unchanged
```

As you can see, `APSR.C` is set to the result of the shift operation, not the `AND` operation.

Now, `AND` is pretty straightforward but in case of e.g. `ADD` you may have carry affected by both the shift and the add. So what happens? Again, ARM ARM to the rescue:

```
if ConditionPassed() then
    EncodingSpecificOperations();
    shift_n = UInt(R[s]<7:0>);
    shifted = Shift(R[m], shift_t, shift_n, APSR.C);
    (result, carry, overflow) = AddWithCarry(R[n], shifted, APSR.C);
    R[d] = result;
    if setflags then
        APSR.N = result<31>;
        APSR.Z = IsZeroBit(result);
        APSR.C = carry;
        APSR.V = overflow;
```

The answer: the add "wins" and the carry of the shift operation is discarded.

BTW, a good page to check what happens for each concrete instruction is [here](http://svr-acjf3-armie.cl.cam.ac.uk/main.cgi). For example:

```
ands r9, r0, r0, ror #3
machine code: E01091E0
...
cpsr.N  ←   (r0 AND r0 ROR 3)<31>
cpsr.Z  ←   r0 AND r0 ROR 3 = 0
cpsr.C  ←   #CARRY (ROR_C (r0,3))
r9  ←   r0 AND r0 ROR 3
r15 ←   r15 + 4


adds r9, r0, r0, ror #3
machine code: E09091E0
...
cpsr.N  ←   (r0 + r0 ROR 3)<31>
cpsr.Z  ←   r0 + r0 ROR 3 = 0
cpsr.C  ←   #CARRY (AddWithCarry (r0,r0 ROR 3,False))
cpsr.V  ←   #OVERFLOW (AddWithCarry (r0,r0 ROR 3,False))
r9  ←   r0 + r0 ROR 3
r15 ←   r15 + 4
```

Comment: Igor, if I meet you in real life at some point, remember me to offer you a drink (what ever you want!). :-)